# Reopen workbook at last active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I reopen my workbook at the last active sheet when I click on a hyperlink that runs ForceReopen? What I have fails because LstSht is not set. (Note that I do not want to save changes when I run ForceReopen.)

```
' Workbook module
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set LstSht = Sh
End Sub

' Standard module
Public LstSht As Worksheet
Sub ForceReopen()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "GoToLast"
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub

Sub GoToLast()
    LstSht.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I understood: You want to close the main workbook, it should not be saved and it should be reopened with the last active sheet. Then this information about the last active sheet can only be stored in memory (or within another workbook that remains open in background, holding your VBA code). As Excel's public variables are gone if you close the workbook I have no idea where else to store that information in memory.

Comment: Now I found a good place "where else" to store the sheet's name and posted an answer which stores it within `Application.Caption` :)

Comment: At my Excel 2016 32bit my suggested solution works, but under 64bit it may be different, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54347086/10908769

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the name of the last active sheet *somwhere*.  Since you don't want to save the file on close, it can't be in the file itself.

One possibility is to create a small text file that contains just the sheet name to activate on file open.  The workbook open event can then read the text file and activate the specified sheet.

The workbook activate event should update the text file.  Provide error handlers to allow for the text file not existing, or the specified sheet not existing.  Depending on how robust you want to make it, you might need to handle the sheet name changing too.

Location of the text file is a design choice:  maybe the same folder as the Excel file, or some fixed config folder.

Another possibility would be to use the registry rather than a text file.

Answer (score 1):

**Remember something during automatic reopen within Application.Caption**

You may store the `ActiveSheet.Name` within `Application.Caption` during a forced reopening of a workbook, even if all other global variables are lost.

```
' Within ThisWorkbook:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Caption = "Last Active: " & ActiveSheet.Name
    ' Stop         ' temporary to see the caption, but restart will not work!
End Sub


' Both following subs within a normal module:
Public Sub ForceReopen()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "GoToLast"
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub

Private Sub GoToLast()
    Dim iLastSheet As Integer  ' Position of text "Last Active" in Caption
    iLastSheet = InStr(Application.Caption, "Last Active:")
    ' Stop     ' temporary to see "Last Active: ..." in the caption
    If iLastSheet > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Mid(Application.Caption, iLastSheet + 13)).Activate
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.Caption = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

If you save the workbook staying in Sheet1 and start `ForceReopen` staying in Sheet3 (by button, by hyperlink, by manual execution, whatever) then it reopens at Sheet3.
To check the functionality, you may add the first `Stop` to see, if `Application.Caption` is set correctly (workbook will not open afterwards, so you have to delete this Stop after testing):

[image: Screenshot to demonstrate the first part]

You may add the second `Stop` to check, if `Application.Caption` is set as intended after it reopened automatically:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot get this to work. How can I test that Application.Caption has been set?

Comment: I can see it being set.

Comment: Is the syntax correct for `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Mid(Application.Caption, test + 13)).Activate`; does it work for you?

Comment: Yes of course, I made a simple workbook just with my code and tested it. Works perfect! Within VBA-Editor you must select "ThisWorkbook" at the folder structure. If you select "Workbook" within the left dropdown list above your editor window and "BeforeClose" within the right dropdown, it should be bold as the sub is still there. The first line of code will only be executed directly before the workbook closes. The line you just mentioned works for me. I added another debugging info to my code.

Comment: I [tested](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90708255899800532576) it by adding a link to ForceReopen on Sheet3, and saving the workbook on Sheet1. When I click the link on Sheet3, the workbook reopens on Sheet1.

Comment: Here it works and I added two screenshots with your example to demonstrate it for other users.

Answer (score -1):

There is a logical flaw in your plan. Why should you activate the last viewed sheet and then close the workbook without saving that change?

1. Set a public variable by the name of LstSht. (I would prefer it to be the sheet name rather than the sheet object but that may be a matter of taste.
2. Set the variable on the Activate event of each sheet. Note that the Activate event may not occur when you first open the workbook. Therefore the variable must also be set in the Workbook_Open event.
3. In the GoToLast procedure provide for the eventuality that the variable doesn't hold a value - just in case. Use `On Error Resume Next`. Also make sure that the sheet isn't activated if it is already active. You may make this procedure a function and let it return True if the sheet was changed (for whatever purpose).

The effect of the whole thing, as you have laid it out, would be that, in the middle of whatever you are doing, the last active sheet is suddenly activated and then the workbook closed without saving your work. Charming idea!