# Excel 2016 shows SaveAs dialog before invoking Workbook_BeforeSave event

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 (64 Bit) shows the SaveAs dialog before invoking Workbook_BeforeSave event.

We have an excel template (.xltm) with an `Workbook_BeforeSave` procedure. It saves the file automatically (with specified path & file name) if the user uses Excels "Save" button or `CTRL+S`.

**This works on previous Excel versions** (2000, 2003, 2010) with 32 Bit. (I could not test with Excel 2013.)

**But Excel 2016 (64 Bit) shows the "SaveAs" dialog first!**

However, I only have to click at 1 of the buttons, then Excel invokes the Workbook_BeforeSave macro.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
        MsgBox "This appears after the SaveAs dialog has opened."
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found:**

Activate the option "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files...".

[Microsoft Excel - Don't show the Backstage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUHxz.png)